# python 2.7 flush to file doesn't work until program terminates

Tags: python, python-2.7, flush

I'm trying to flush all of std out to a python file via:

```
sys.stdout = open('myfile.txt', 'w')
print("Starting work")
sys.stdout.flush()
whole bunch of stuff with prints and sys.stdout.flush() mixed in
print("ending work")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Unfortunately, nothing prints until the script terminates. The file size remains 0 kb. I am doing this on a windows machine if that helps with python 2.7

Thank you!

Comment: Can you do `sys.stdout = open('file', 'w', 0)` to stop any buffering?

Comment: Flushing isn't enough, you need to`close` the file.

Comment: @MarkRansom: But how do I close the file while the program is still running? That wouldn't work....

Comment: @MarkRansom Why isn't flushing enough? What do you think it does?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print what you've written should work.

Comment: @Barmar: and yet it does not.

Comment: Does it work if you do `sys.stdout.write()` instead of `print`?

Comment: @Barmar flushing makes sure all the data gets to the OS, but it doesn't guarantee the OS will finish writing it to disk. Screen output is different than file output.

Comment: @MarkRansom We're not talking about writing to disk. The question says that the OS says that the file size is 0 bytes. If it gets to the OS, it should update the file size.

Comment: @MarkRansom To get it to the disk, closing isn't enough -- you have to `fsync()`.